# Como armazenar e resgatar valor da session através de jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, mobile, intel-xdk

Eu estou a desenvolver uma aplicação móvel com intel XDK eu tenho de fazer um `login` que irá ser validado pelo ficheiro php que contém todas as validações e por fim armazena em `session` os valores que preciso do `user` não sei e como posso resgatar esses valores para listar na próxima pagina quando o `login` for efectuado com sucesso.
se possível gostava que me indicassem a melhor solução e uma base de como pode ser feito.

Comment: Faça com [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), retorne faça seu arquivo `php` retornar os dados do `user` que estão na sessão, faça uma requisição ajax e receba este retorno.

Comment: Sim mas essa sessão como vai ficar guardar e no telemovel ainda nao percebi muito bem

Comment: Seu arquivo `PHP` você vai fazer normalmente o controle da sessão, o *ajax* faz requisições identicas aos de um `form`, porém sem a necessidade de recarregar a página.

Comment: e faco outro arquivo PHP com os dados do user e retorno um json com o dados para mostrar certo ?

Comment: É uma das soluções.

Comment: Mas posso pegar logo do mesmo ficheiro onde declaro a session se sim podia dar como resposta um exemplo simples de como ficaria

Comment: Observa a resposta e vê se atende à sua necessidade

Answer (score 2):

### Php

```
// Antes faça toda a declaraçao da sessão
function getUserSession(){
    return json_encode($_SESSION["user"]);
}

// Verifica se o login foi executado
if($login){
    getUserSession();
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$.post( "arquivo.php", { user: "John", password: "*****" }, function( data ) {
  console.log(data); // Retorna os dados da sessão do usuário logado, ou da falha na autenticação em formato jSon
}, "json");
```

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor sua resposta? Ela está muito superficial...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar caba chato, kkkkkkk, blz vou colocar um exemplo de ajax também em breve

Comment: @FelipeAvelar pronto, um exemplo prático de como executar a ação